io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno when trying to write pdf from .zip to MinIO
I'm working on a Flask app where a user uploads a .zip file populated with .pdf files and I want to upload its contents to minIO. Been trying to use the put_object function, but I'm having issues trying to get the size.
Tried to replicate this question, but I'm having troubles with the fileno method:
file = form.file.data
file.seek(0)
zipfile = ZipFile(BytesIO(file.read()))
files = [zipfile.open(file_name) for file_name in zipfile.namelist()]

client = Minio(host_minio, access_key=access, secret_key=secret, secure=False)

destination_file = f'folder/file.pdf'

specific_file = files[0]

specific_file.seek(0)

file_bytes = BytesIO(specific_file.read())

size = os.fstat(file_bytes.fileno()).st_size


client .put_object(
            bucket_name, destination_file, file_bytes , size
        )

Here, size is giving me the following error:
 io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno

Is this the correct approach? What am I missing? Thanks!

Found my answer after some tinkering. This works:
client.put_object(
    bucket, destination_file, file_bytes, len(file_bytes.getvalue())
)

